# : Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

Tags: django, python-2.7

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
>   Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named MySQLdb

Tell me the solution where I can change the code

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. Post some comments, not error code only.

Comment: You don't change the code - you install the module. Its obvious that the module is missing **No module named MySQLdb** is right there in the error message!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install `MySQL-python`. It can be done, for example, using [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/):

```
pip install MySQL-python
```

Also, you'll need some libs to be able to install it. In Debian linux it can be done by following command:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pip install mysqlclient`. For me, `pip install MySQL-python` doesn't always work on my Windows.

Reference: [Official documentation on MySQL DB API drivers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#mysql-db-api-drivers)